# How can I efficiently shuffle the tuples that itertools.combinations() produces?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am using `itertools.combinations()` to generate a list of two-item tuples based off a list of non-repetitive elements. I then shuffle the list produced. However, the contents of the tuples themselves are organized chronologically. For example, running the code below:

```py
import random
import itertools
items = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
item_combos = list(itertools.combinations(items, 2))
random.shuffle(item_combos)
print(item_combos)
```

outputs this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
[('b', 'd'), ('a', 'e'), ('b', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('c', 'e'), ('c', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('d', 'e')]
```

The characters are ordered within the tuples by when they appear in the input list (Not alphabetically, the input list just happens to be alphabetically sorted. Scrambling the list would not solve the problem, just hide it). 'c' will always appear to the left of 'd', 'a' will always appear left of everything else.

My solution is to simply replace all the tuples with scrambled tuples (shown below). This works, but proves to be exceedingly slow, especially on larger lists.

```py
for i in range(len(item_combos)):
    item_combos[i] = tuple(random.sample(item_combos[i], 2))
```

Is there a faster way to do this that yields similar outputs?

Comment: I don't think there's a better way. `combinations()` always returns the results in order according to the input.

Comment: Is it possible you want `itertools.permutations()` rather than `itertools.combinations()`.  It seems that you consider `(b, a)` and `(a, b)` to be different.  But if you really only want one of those, but you want its internal to be random, you want the code you've got.

Comment: first `random.shuffle(items)` then `itertools`

Comment: @cards The characters will still be in a specific order, though it will be the one they have after your shuffle instead of their original one;

Comment: If you know the tuples are all just 2 items, you could randomly choose which tuples to reverse (the only possible way to re-order them).

Comment: Do you know that all the tuples are just two items? How large do the lists get? How slow is exceedingly slow? Or, to answer these questions and more all at once: what are you using this for?

Comment: the title may be in contradiction with the question in the OP, `itertools` yes, no, perhaps?

Comment: Like @ScottHunter said, instead of `random.sample` on every combo, I wonder if it's quicker to probabilistically reverse them, something like `if random.random()<0.5: item_combos[i] = item_combos[i][::-1]`.

Comment: Have you tried `sample()` as part of the initial construction of `item_combos`? Maybe `item_combos = [tuple(random.sample(t, count)) for t in itertools.combinations(items, count)]` where `count=2`?

Comment: If it's OK for the order of different tuples to be correlated in your output (e.g. `('a', 'b')` and `('b', 'c')` implies `('a', 'c')`), you could `random.shuffle` your `items` list before getting the combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of scrambling each tuple, choosing random tuples to reverse works much faster. This has the same result, as each tuple in `item_combos` only contain two items.

New tuple "scrambling" code:

```py
for i in range(len(item_combos)):
    if random.random()<.5:
        item_combos[i] = item_combos[i][::-1]
```

Comment: `random.random` is also faster. But better use `<` to make it unbiased. And it would be good to measure/show how much faster this is.

Comment: It's consistently about 3x faster